# Prove: if $f \in Hol(\mathbb{C}\setminus \{0\}),$ if $f$ is one to one and onto, then $f = az$ or $f = \frac{a}{z}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Prove: if $f \in Hol(\mathbb{C}\setminus \{0\}),$ if $f$ is one to one and onto, then
$f = az$ or $f = \frac{a}{z}$

I know that in order to solve this I have to examine the singularities of $f$ at the points $0$ and $\infty$. I've proved that these cases can't exist:

1. both of them are removable singularities
2. either of them is an essential singularity

I'm having trouble disproving the case in which both of the points are poles. Also, I can't think of the case in which one of the singularities is a pole and the other is removable - why does the pole have to be simple.

I think perhaps the way I've approached the problem is at fault. It seem's like a constructive proof would be simpler.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that [meromorphic functions on the Riemann sphere are rational](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/123259/why-is-every-meromorphic-function-on-hat-mathbbc-a-rational-function). Since you've dealt with the case where either singularity is essential, this means that you only need to look at rational functions whose only poles are at $0$ and $\infty$. Fortunately, the supply of those is relatively limited...

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thanks!